# php SimpleImage library keep updating the original file. where is the error?

Tags: php

I am manipulating some images with php and have decided to use [this library](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage) as it seems to fit my need perfectly. My issue is that the `save()` method continues to overwrite the original file instead of creating b.jpg.

My php file:

```
<?php 
    include "lib/SimpleImage.php";
    $img = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage($_GET["path_source"]);
    $img->rotate(90);
    $img->save($_GET["path_dest"]);
?>
```

I'm passing argument path_source=img/a.jpg and path_dest=img/b.jpg

What i'm doing wrong?

I've also opened [a issue](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage/issues/24) on the github page of the library.

Comment: can't you use http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php ?

Comment: i need a convert feature....looks like Imagick don't have it...

Comment: try hardcoding: SimpleImage("img/a.jpg"), save("img/b.jpg"); there is nothing in code which would overwrite original picture. Only line 153: $filename = $filename ?: $this->filename; which overwrites to original filename if output filename is empty. Maybe params are $_POST and not $_GET? Maybe some whitespace? Try $_REQUEST

Comment: i've already tried to hardcode the pats but the result is the same. you can see it here: [link](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage/issues/24)

Comment: Please check that you have php >= 5.3. The syntax used in the simpleimage library $filename = $filename ?: $this->filename; is probably not valid with your version of php.

Comment: phpinfo() says: PHP Version 5.4.7

Comment: I have tried the same as you do in my machine and it's working fine. please show us the output of var_dump($_GET["path_source"]) and var_dump($_GET["path_dest"])

Comment: @yannSagon I've solved it. read my answer. thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Yann Sagon i've found out that thar syntax:

```
$filename   = $filename ?: $this->filename;
```

(used in the library) is not supported by my version of php

changed it to:

```
if($filename==null){
        $filename=$this->filename;
        }
```